# Can a parquet file exceed 2.1GB?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, parquet, fastparquet

I'm having an issue storing a large dataset (around 40GB) in a *single* parquet file.

I'm using the `fastparquet` library to append `pandas.DataFrames` to this parquet dataset file. The following is a minimal example program that appends chunks to a parquet file until it crashes as the file-size in bytes exceeds the int32 threshold of 2147483647 (2.1GB):

[Link to minimum reproducible example code](https://gist.github.com/sikanrong/d4b2f62bfb17f19bca4946ce8cce37a3)

Everything goes fine until the dataset hits 2.1GB, at which point I get the following errors:

```
OverflowError: value too large to convert to int
Exception ignored in: 'fastparquet.cencoding.write_thrift'
```

Because the exception is ignored internally, it's very hard to figure out which specific thrift it's upset about and get a stack trace. However, it's very clear that it is linked to the file size exceeding the int32 range.

Also these thrift definitions come from the parquet format repo *itself*, so I wonder if this is a limitation built into the design of the parquet format?

Comment: It can exceed 2.3 GB. How are you appending rows? Its best if you share the code snippet.

Comment: @shetty15 I updated my question to contain the explicit code snippet that illustrates how exactly I'm writing to the parquet file

Comment: @shetty15 today I've updated the question to link to a gist with minimal example code that reproduces the issue. The code snippet is dead-simple, and I feel like it should work. Yet, it crashes right when the filesize exceeds int32 bounds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured out that I was running into a genuine bug in the python library `fastparquet`, which resulted in a fix in the main library.

This is [a link to the salient issue on Github](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/825).

The commit in which the issue is fixed is [89d16a2](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/commit/89d16a29d1817884539fbcdb2e2f971714f3fbe6).

Comment: Interesting find. Looks like it's been increased now to 64 bits.